# playback recorded content in AVCapture

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I am trying to playback the recorded session in full view after it is recorder.
Kind of like "snapchat".

I can record and play the videoplay back in a UIView, but it is shown with "play", "Done" "Stop" buttons. I don't want that. I want it to look like snapchat.

This is my code, where i found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36013349/4545564), but I modified a tiny little bit. :)

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AssetsLibrary
import Photos
import MediaPlayer
import AVKit

class Camera: UIViewController, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {


@IBOutlet var cameraView: UIView!
var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
var captureDevice:AVCaptureDevice!
var CamChoser = false

var moviePlayer: MPMoviePlayerController?
@IBOutlet weak var playback: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var exitCameraModeButton: UIButton!
@IBAction func exitCameraModeButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}


var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

lazy var cameraDevice: AVCaptureDevice? = {
    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devicesWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) as! [AVCaptureDevice]
    return devices.filter{$0.position == .Front}.first
}()

lazy var micDevice: AVCaptureDevice? = {
    return AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)
}()

var movieOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()

private var tempFilePath: NSURL = {

    let tempPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).URLByAppendingPathComponent("tempMovie").URLByAppendingPathExtension("mp4").absoluteString
    if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(tempPath) {
        do {
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(tempPath)
        } catch { }
    }
    return NSURL(string: tempPath)!
}()

private var library = ALAssetsLibrary()
//private var library = PHPhotoLibrary()

@IBOutlet weak var switchCameraButton: UIButton!
@IBAction func switchCameraButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    //startSession()
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //start session configuration

    captureSession.beginConfiguration()
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh

    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()
    startSession()
}

func startSession() {

    // add device inputs (front camera and mic)
    print(CamChoser)

        captureSession.addInput(deviceInputFromDevice(cameraDevice))
        captureSession.addInput(deviceInputFromDevice(micDevice))

        // add output movieFileOutput
        movieOutput.movieFragmentInterval = kCMTimeInvalid
        captureSession.addOutput(movieOutput)

        // start session
        captureSession.commitConfiguration()
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        self.cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
        self.cameraView.bringSubviewToFront(self.exitCameraModeButton)
        self.cameraView.bringSubviewToFront(self.switchCameraButton)
        previewLayer?.frame = self.cameraView.layer.frame
        captureSession.startRunning()
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    print("touch")
    // start capture

    movieOutput.startRecordingToOutputFileURL(tempFilePath, recordingDelegate: self)

}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    print("release")
    //stop capture
    movieOutput.stopRecording()

    let videoUrl = movieOutput.outputFileURL
    moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: videoUrl)
    moviePlayer!.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.Unknown
    moviePlayer!.view.frame = playback.bounds
    moviePlayer!.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFill
    moviePlayer!.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Embedded
    moviePlayer!.shouldAutoplay = true

    playback.addSubview((moviePlayer?.view)!)
    //moviePlayer!.prepareToPlay()
    moviePlayer?.setFullscreen(true, animated: true)
    moviePlayer!.play()
    cameraView.bringSubviewToFront(playback)




}

private func deviceInputFromDevice(device: AVCaptureDevice?) -> AVCaptureDeviceInput? {
    guard let validDevice = device else { return nil }
    do {
        return try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: validDevice)
    } catch let outError {
        print("Device setup error occured \(outError)")
        return nil
    }
}

func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL fileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!) {
}

func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL outputFileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) {
    if (error != nil) {
        print("Unable to save video to the iPhone  \(error.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
        // save video to photo album
        library.writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputFileURL, completionBlock: { (assetURL: NSURL?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("Unable to save video to the iPhone \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            }
        })

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Just so you know, MPMoviePlayerController has been deprecated for iOS 9. The issue is your control style is set to embedded which by default, displays the control buttons. Use `MPMovieControleStyle.None` to remove the controls.

See [MPMovieControlStyle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/MPMovieControlStyle) documentation for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the help jon, but is there an alternative solution now when MPMoviePlayerController has been deprecated for iOS ?

Comment: Use AVPictureInPictureController instead. Also, make sure you select my answer instead of upvoting it if I've helped :)

Comment: well.. it kind of helped but still not :) 
what I'm trying to do is to make this :
        moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: receivedURL)
        moviePlayer!.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.Unknown
        moviePlayer!.view.frame = view.bounds
        moviePlayer!.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFill
        moviePlayer!.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None
        moviePlayer!.shouldAutoplay = true
        view.addSubview((moviePlayer?.view)!)
        moviePlayer?.setFullscreen(true, animated: true)
        moviePlayer!.play()
but with AVPlayerViewcontroller()